# Compiling code from within IntelliJ

Tags: ceylon

I've managed to compile and execute Cyelon code in the ['Walkthrough' repository](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/walkthrough/), by right clicking a function and choosing 'Run functionName'.

I've also tried creating my own Ceylon-project (named POSTtoFile) and seeing if I could execute a 'Hello World' function from there. I couldn't. I guess I have to create some sort of build configuration for my project, but I don't know what to fill into these form fields:

[image]

The [Installing Ceylon IDE for IntelliJ](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/ide/intellij/install/#installing_ceylon_ide_for_intellij) guide is completely silent on this question. It would be neat if it had included a section named 'making your first Ceylon'-project. It's embarrasing to know that all previous readers of that document must have known that stuff in advance. So here I am! The single exception.

In the 'Ceylon module' drop down, there is a single option, named `module default "unversioned"`. I tried choosing that one and then clicking 'Run' -> 'Run POSTtoFile'. I got this output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dceylon.system.repo=C:\Users\Jon\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\CeylonIDEA\classes\embeddedDist\repo -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Jon\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\CeylonIDEA\classes\embeddedDist\lib\ceylon-bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap run --run "" default/unversioned
ceylon run: Module default/unversioned not found in the following repositories:
 C:\Users\Jon\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\CeylonIDEA\classes\embeddedDist\repo
 C:\Users\Jon\Auchitect\POSTtoFile\modules
 C:\Users\Jon\.ceylon\cache
 https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1
 [Maven] Aether
 [NPM] npm

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT:

As can be seen in the screenshot below, I have no toolbar in the bottom of the IntelliJ window, and I see no tool window named 'Ceylon problems':

[image]

As to your other questions:

- The 'modules' folder is empty
- IntelliJ seems to do work when I click  `Build>Rebuild Project`. This is the output:

[image]

- These are my version numbers:

[image]

- When I put the folowing code in my `main.ceylon`file:

  shared void hello() {
      print("Hello , World!");
  }

(sorry, stack overflow won't format this as code, even though I have 4 spaces in front of each line)

I get the green arrow to the left of the function `hello`, but then I can't click on it. It says 'Nothing here':

[image]

EDIT 2:
I tried moving the source code file (`main.ceilon`) from the root directory (`POSTtoFile`) to the source directory (`POSTtoFile/source`).
Then I clicked `Run` -> `Run 'POSTtoFile'`.

This gave me the following new output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dceylon.system.repo=C:\Users\Jon\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\CeylonIDEA\classes\embeddedDist\repo -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Jon\.IdeaIC2016.3\config\plugins\CeylonIDEA\classes\embeddedDist\lib\ceylon-bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap run --run "" default/unversioned
ceylon run: String index out of range: 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at ceylon.modules.api.runtime.AbstractRuntime.invokeRun(AbstractRuntime.java:53)
 at ceylon.modules.api.runtime.AbstractRuntime.execute(AbstractRuntime.java:105)
 at ceylon.modules.api.runtime.AbstractRuntime.execute(AbstractRuntime.java:101)
 at ceylon.modules.Main.execute(Main.java:69)
 at ceylon.modules.Main.main(Main.java:42)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:308)
 at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:487)
 at ceylon.modules.bootstrap.CeylonRunTool.run(CeylonRunTool.java:292)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.common.tools.CeylonTool.run(CeylonTool.java:547)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.common.tools.CeylonTool.execute(CeylonTool.java:423)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Launcher.runInJava7Checked(Launcher.java:108)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:38)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:31)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap.runVersion(Bootstrap.java:162)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap.runInternal(Bootstrap.java:117)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:93)
 at com.redhat.ceylon.launcher.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:85)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 2
```

This is the content of `main.ceilon`:

```
shared void hello() {
    print("Hello , World!");
}
```

EDIT 3:

After changing the content of `main.ceilon` to this:

```
void hello() {
    print("Hello, World!");
}

hello();
```

I get this output when doing `Run` -> `Run 'POSTtoFile'`:

[image]

*and* now all of a sudden I have the `Ceylon problems` button in the bottom toolbar! It says I have three problems:

```
incorrect syntax: no viable alternative at token end of file.
missing declaration or argument name.
not an annotation constructor: hello
```

I don't understand why I get errors, though, as my code is straight out of the [Tour of Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/#a_really_simple_program).

Comment: A few questions to help me find out what's going on: do you see a tool window named 'Ceylon problems' in the bottom tool bar? If yes, it means that Ceylon is correctly configured in your project. Do you see anything in the `modules` directory? (it should be marked as an output directory). Does anything change if you do a Build>Rebuild Project? What version of IntelliJ and Ceylon IDE are you using?

Comment: If everything is configured correctly, once you create a file and put a `shared` top-level function with no parameters in it, a green arrow should appear on the left. You can use it to automatically build and run the code.

Comment: @BastienJansen I have updated my question with answers to your questions. Thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, the documentation lacks a "Getting started with IntelliJ" section, I'm going to fix that this week.

Here are the steps needed to run a simple project in IntelliJ.

Create a new project via `File > New > Project` and choose the `Ceylon` category.

[image: New Ceylon project]

Click `Next` and choose whether you want to compile/run your project on the JVM, on JS or both:

[image: Ceylon project wizard: choose target platforms]

Click `Next` twice, enter a name for your project and click `Finish`. Your project is now ready to host new Ceylon code:

[image: Project structure]

In the Project view, you can see a few existing files and folders:

- `.ceylon` contains internal configuration that can be reused by the CLI tools, you shouldn't have to modify it directly most of the time.
- `modules` is the output directory where Ceylon modules will be compiled.
- `resource` contains [resources](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/current/tour/modules/#resources)
- `source` contains [source modules](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/current/tour/modules/)

To add Ceylon code to this project, you can either put files directly under the `source` folder to add them to the `default` module, or create a new module and add source files to this module. In both cases, `.ceylon` files *must* be in the `source` folder, not directly in the project folder.

- To add a file to the `default` module, right-click on the `source` folder and choose `New > Ceylon File/Declaration`, enter a name (for example `run`) and click `OK`.
- To create a new module, right-click on the `source` folder and choose `New > Ceylon Module`, enter a name like `my.ceylon.example`, adjust the version if you don't like `1.0.0`, set the runnable unit name to something like `run` and click `OK`. New folders will be created (`my/ceylon/example`), along with a module descriptor (`module.ceylon`), a package descriptor (`package.ceylon`) and your runnable unit (`run.ceylon`).

At this point, a tool window titled `Ceylon Problems` should be present in the bottom tool bar, indicating that the IDE is now aware that the project contains Ceylon code and is correctly configured:

[image: Ceylon Problems view]

Now that the project is set up, it's time to actually add code :). Open `run.ceylon` and add the following code:

```
shared void run() {
    print("hello");
}
```

A green arrow will appear in the left gutter, click on that arrow to run or debug the `run` function:

[image: Run Ceylon function]

Click on `Run 'run'`, this will automatically create a run configuration, build the project and print `hello`:

[image: Running the file prints 'hello']

Regarding your last error:

> incorrect syntax: no viable alternative at token end of file.

Just like Java and its `main()` method, when you declare a runnable function in Ceylon, you don't have to actually call it manually. The Ceylon runner will do it for you (either the IDE or `ceylon run` when you use the CLI). Ceylon only accepts toplevel *declarations*, not statements, so this code triggers a parse error when it's found at the root of a file:

```
hello();
```

This is a bit misleading if you've already tried the [web IDE](https://try.ceylon-lang.org) because the web IDE automatically wraps your code in a `run` function under the hood, so the above statement would never be a *toplevel* statement.

Comment: Now it works, but only if I explicitly run the hello function. If I just do Run -> Run -> POSTtoFile, I get that long error message you can see in my post above.
So if I haven't got any modules, how do I then specify a 'runable unit name' for my project, or my main.ceylon file?

Comment: found it :)
Its the 'Runnable declaration in the Run -> 'build configuration' window